# ICS App Drawers, how to give them a name?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, launcher, home-screen-shortcuts

I own a Samsung Nexus S and Yesterday I was able to upgrade to Android 4.0.4. When I upgraded, I saw that Google had created an app drawer full of Google apps, and it has the Word Google underneath it. I know it is possible to create app drawers by dragging app shortcuts on top of one another, but is there a way to give an app drawer a name the way Google has done with the Google drawer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's done like on the Galaxy Nexus, just open the folder, tap the text `Unnamed folder` and write your own label :)

Comment: You know, I didn't see the text at the bottom of the expanded drawer until you said that. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, took me about a week to notice it :) Glad to help!